# how do i get my routes navigating to the correct page

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, laravel-8, shared-hosting

I deployed my project to hostinger and on the home page i can easily navigate to the about, contact, login , register and other pages. the problem states when i login. as a user instead of navigating to the user dashboard it goes to the admin dashboard. and any link i click on the user side menu takes me to the home page. like wise as an admin, any link i click on takes be back to the homepage. for example as an admin when i click on the " view all users" link i am redirected to the site homepage. i have tried several answers on here about changing my htaccess redirect rules to no avail. below is a copy of my current htaccess file, and any other information needed i would gladly provide. at first i couldnt even get the homepage to load(404 error, then 500 server error) so i know im making progress. i am stuck here and any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[my folder structure if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzTwi.png)

that is my folder structure on my hostinger hpanel

below are my web.php, admin routes and user routes
[web.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaFgi.png) 1. web.php

[user routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx41g.png) 2. user routes

[admin routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGRjB.png) 3. admin routes

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your .htaccess is very unlikely to b the culprit here - basically all it does, is rewrite those URLs to the index.php for further processing. This really needs more information - we don't know what links you are creating in your HTML output to begin with, whether your app automatically redirects after the login and if so, how, etc.